# Can DC grounds for 48V to 12 Volt Converters be shared?

Tags: wiring

In my RV, I've run batteries in a series for 48 volts. I'm running that 48 volts DC to (4) 48V to 12V converters. These Converters have a NEG for the 48V input and a NEG for the 12V Output. My question is: Can these Converters share the same ground for both the 48V GND and the 12 Volt NEG outputs for these converters? NOTE: Currently, all negative and GRN terminals for all other electrical is grounded on the frame of the 5th wheel.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B089Y49LWT/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_image_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089Y49LWT)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Great question! I ass/u/me you can, but don't know for sure. I'd like to know the answer as well :o)

Comment: Beware the cheap Chinese.  Not least, there's no tech support - if you ask them "Is it OK to install 4 of these in parallel for ampacity", they cannot tell you "yes, we designed and tested for that" or "no, that would be bad" *because they don't know*. The 3rd party seller is just buying them for 3 dollars a unit off Alibaba, and tossing them on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

One of the photos for the 24v version in the link that you posted shows the underneath of the PCB -

[image]

You can see on the left that the two black wires are connected to the same copper, so they are already connected together.

This however does not mean that the 48v version is the same, but you could have a look inside at the board to see if the 2 black wires are already connected together.

Comment: Thanks Howie.  My plan is to run the Auto Leveling to the 60amp, One 30amp to Slide-outs, One 30amp to pumps and sound system and one 30amp to the Main Hub for everything else. Sounds like over-kill but I feel safer sharing the loads and having backups.